# What does the error "AjaxUpdate component not found for id:" mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a code like this :

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.method1}" reRender="outputPanel,statusPanel,viewLog">
            <a4j:support event="oncomplete" action="#" reRender="outputPanel,statusPanel,viewLog" ajaxSingle="true"></a4j:support>
            <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{myBean.method2}" reRender="statusPanel"/>
        </a4j:commandButton>
```

This was working fine in JSF 1.x. But after migrating to JSF 2.1, I get the error "**AjaxUpdate component not found for id:** ". Once I click on the Submit button. Which component is JSF looking for and what does "AjaxUpdate component" mean ? And what is the alternate to this ?

The requirement is, When the user clicks on the button, I need to call the "**method2**" and update the "**statusPanel**" , which is just an textbox. And then the "**method1**" needs to fire. Also, once the "method1" is complete, I need to rerender all the panels with the updated info.

Answer (score 1):

I also had faced same issue, got resolved by adding corresponding status component.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="apply-reject-filter" value="Filter" style="width:120px"  styleClass="dlg-button"
                          action="#{bean}"
                          title="Filter"
                           status="waitStatus1"
                          limitToList="true" reRender="rejectedParticipantList"/>


<a4j:status id="waitStatus1" forceId="true"
            onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('waitModalPanel1');"
            onstop="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('waitModalPanel1');" />

<rich:modalPanel id="waitModalPanel1" autosized="true" width="200"
           height="120" moveable="false" resizeable="false">
           <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="Processing" />
           </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="Please wait..." />
           <center>
               <h:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
           </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning (it is displayed only in Development mode). It says that ajax cannot find the element in the tree to update (one of outputPanel,statusPanel,viewLog were not rendered, so not present in the DOM tree). For more details about the issue refer here: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/outputPanel.jsf?c=outputPanel&tab=usage

And you can simplify your code (currently it does too much (it may send up to three! requests to make a single action)), improved version may look like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                   action="#{myBean.method2}"
                   reRender="statusPanel"
                   oncomplete="callMethod1AndRenderAllPanels()"/>

<a4j:jsFunction name="callMethod1AndRenderAllPanels"
                action="#{myBean.method1}"
                ajaxSingle="true"
                reRender="outputPanel,statusPanel,viewLog"/>
```

Btw I don't see a reason not to do this all at once:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                   action="#{myBean.invokeBothMethods}"
                   reRender="outputPanel,statusPanel,viewLog"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey for the response .. The AjaxUpdate error is not showing up now .. But I am still not able to get it working (Nothing is happening in the UI).. one doubt that I had is if any exception is thrown from the bean method, "method1" , the reRender code will get executed or not .. And if not, how we ensure that reRender is getting invoked even if an exception is thrown from the method..